# How to get test data of Adhar card using Rest Api in java

Tags: java, rest, authentication

I am trying to get test data of Adhar card using test APIs defined in https://authportal.uidai.gov.in/web/uidai/developer
But it's not working.  I am trying using rest Client to call these api .

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the aadhaar details so easily. You have to call their web services which required digitally signed request (prefered https) 
Following are the links which you might help
https://authportal.uidai.gov.in/developer

http://indiastack.org/aadhaar/